# Dynamic imports of routes using vite for vuejs lead to blank pages in prod

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vite

I was trying to build a Vue JS application using Vite where it should be possible to choose between different views depending on the value of an environment variable. The idea behind this, was to be able to build different version of the application for different customers.

```
├── vite@4.4.9
├── vue@3.3.4
```

I have a customer config looking like this:

```js
export type CustomerConfig = {
  importMyView: () => Promise<unknown>;
};
```

The default implementation

```js
export const config: CustomerConfig = {
  importMyView: () => import("@/views/MyView.vue")
};
```

And let's say, the implement for customer1

```js
export const config: CustomerConfig = {
  importMyView: () => import("@/views/customer1/MyView.vue")
};
```

In my router, I tried to use the function from the plugin to be able to switch the view that should be loaded. The router looks like this:

```js
const config = useConfig();

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: config.importMyView
  },
```

The config is choose based on the value of the variable `VITE_CUSTOMER`. I have different .env files and I use `--mode CUSTOMER` to switch from one to another config.

```js
import type { UserConfig } from "@/config/config";

const config = (
  await import(
    `../config/config-${
      import.meta.env.VITE_CUSTOMER
        ? import.meta.env.VITE_CUSTOMER
        : "default"
    }.ts`
  )
).config;

export function useConfig(): UserConfig {
  return config;
}
```

Somehow, this seems to work perfectly in dev mode (with `npm sun dev`), but once built and run in a container for example, the page is just blank. No errors in the browser console or anything that could help.

Note that also tried with `importMyView: () => import("@/views/MyView.vue")` without success.

Do you guys have an idea of what could be the cause of the problem? Is my approach maybe simply wrong?

Comment: I think you need the defineAsyncComponent on vue3, try `defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@/views/MyView.vue"))`. (you will need the import also `import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'`)

Comment: thanks @lk77, thanks for the quick answer. I tired it but the problem remains. In dev, the view is loaded, in prod not :(

Comment: in fact, the issue seems to not be caused by the import of the component itself, but by calling `const config = useConfig();` in the router